# This stylization needs a name!

Tags: cipher, visual

Although I have been toying with this idea for a while, posting it in this form was inspired by @Stiv's ["needs a name" puzzle series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A60644+title%3A%22needs+a+name%22).

I didn't come up with this cipher, but I have never seen it stylized like this before.
What is it's name?

[image: ciphertext]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This at first appears to be

> pigpen cipher, taking each three rows as a single character, spelling out `ELIANPIOELJCRIPK`.

Then,

> the first few letters look meaningful. "Elian script" is another writing system that uses a pigpen-like grid, but doesn't use the "X" shape of the pigpen cipher: instead, it has two different variations on each glyph. And in fact, if we turn Elian clockwise, it lines up with the first two grids of Pigpen. So, this is actually Elian, not pigpen! If we turn the grid 90 degrees counter-clockwise, we can read off the actual message as Elian script: **ELIAN PIXEL SCRIPT**.

Comment: Wow that was quick! This one was definitely too easy ;) Thanks Deusovi!

Comment: @Berry, Too easy for a few old timers may be ;)

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh You're absolutely right. I also didn't mean to take away from Deusovi's achievement. I'm just so very impressed ;) As long as people enjoy solving my puzzles I don't care about how quickly they were solved.